# Replace one accentued characters in php

Tags: php, character, non-ascii-characters

I have a string with one french accentued character (ex : lycée).

I want just replace one character but accentued character is like 2 characters and result is never good :

```
$str='lycée';
$str[3]='o';
echo $str;
```

Result would be :

```
lycoe
```

But result is

```
lyco�e
```

(All settings is set to UTF8 : php.ini, meta charset, mb_internal_encoding, notepad++ file encoding...)

When I use substr_replace function I have the same problem.

If I use :

```
$str= iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$str);
```

Problem is moving to other character :

```
$str='lycée';
$str= iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$str);
$str[2]='o';

echo $str;
```

Result :

```
lyo?e
```

Can somebody help me ??

I just have the position of character.

I would like:

```
$str[2]='o'  -> lyoée
$str[3]='o'  -> lycoe
$str[4]='o'  -> lycéo
...
```

Comment: how about using `str_replace` or `mb_str_replace`

Comment: I don't know the character. I just have the position

Comment: UTF-8 uses multiple bytes to encode non-ascii characters, that explains your problem. You only replace one of several bytes for the `é` character.

Comment: I have found the solution !!! this is the mb_substr_replace function (https://gist.github.com/stemar/8287074)

Comment: ah ok you have an answer, well i have another below if its any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$str='lycée';

//$str[3]='o';
//echo $str;


function mbStringToArray ($string) {
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    while ($strlen) {
        $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8");
        $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8");
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    }
    return $array;
} 
$new_str=mbStringToArray($str);
$new_str[3]='o';
echo implode($new_str); //output: lycoe
```

function mbStringToArray from the manual page for mb_split